# Download app center artifact from Appcenter in Gitlab CI

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-ci, visual-studio-app-center

I'm working in Gitlab CI for application building by Appcenter. My script in build stage like below. I want to ask additional command to download the artifact from that build when it done and save as artifact in GitlabCI ? Thanks

```
stage: build
  image: cirrusci/flutter
  before_script:
    - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
    - npm install --global appcenter-cli
  script:
    - appcenter login --token $APPTOKEN
    - appcenter build queue --app "$APP_NAME --branch "$CURRENT_BRANCH" --token $APPTOKEN
```